# WebHCat & Pig - how to pass a parameter file to the job?

Tags: apache-pig, hcatalog

I am using HCatalog's WebHCat API to run Pig jobs, such as documented here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+Reference+Pig

I have no problem running a simple job but I would like to attach a parameters file to the job, such as one can do using pig command line's parameter: `--param_file` .

I assume this is possible through `arg` request's parameter, so I tried multiple things, such as passing:

```
'arg': '-param_file /path/to/param.file'
```

or:

```
'arg': {'param_file': '/path/to/param.file'}
```

None seems to work, and error stacks don't say much. 
I would love to know if this is possible, and if so, how to correctly achieve this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct usage:

```
'arg': ['-param_file', '/path/to/param.file']
```

Explanation:
By passing the value in arg,

```
'arg': {'-param_file': '/path/to/param.file'}
```

webhcat generates "-param_file" for the command prompt.
Pig throws the following error

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Can not create a Path from a null string
```

Using a comma instead of the colon operator passes the path to file as a second argument.
webhcat will generate "-param_file" "/path/to/param.file"

P.S: I am using Requests library on python to make the REST calls